# How to resume properly the training of a network from a tensorflow checkpoint file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, restore, checkpoint

I am struggling to restore a model for one day without any success. My code consists of a `class TF_MLPRegressor()`, where I define the network architecture within the constructor. Then I invoke the `fit()` function to do the training. So this is how I save a simple Perceptron model with 1 hidden layer within the `fit()` function:

```
            starting_epoch = 0
            # Launch the graph
            tf.set_random_seed(self.random_state)   # fix the random seed before creating the Session in order to take effect!
            if hasattr(self, 'sess'):
                self.sess.close()
                del self.sess   # delete Session to release memory
                gc.collect()
            self.sess = tf.Session(config=self.config) # save the session to predict from new data
            # Create a saver object which will save all the variables
            saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)  # max_to_keep=2 means to not keep more than 2 checkpoint files
            self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# ... (each 100 epochs)

            saver.save(self.sess, self.checkpoint_dir+"/resume", global_step=epoch)
```

Then I create a new `TF_MLPRegressor()` instance with exactly the same input parameter values and invoke the `fit()` function to restore the model like this:

```
    self.sess = tf.Session(config=self.config)  # create a new session to load saved variables
    ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(self.checkpoint_dir)
    starting_epoch = int(ckpt.split('-')[-1])
    metagraph = ".".join([ckpt, 'meta'])
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(metagraph)
    self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())    # Initialize variables
    lhl = tf.trainable_variables()[2]
    lhlA = lhl.eval(session=self.sess)
    saver.restore(sess=self.sess, save_path=ckpt)   # Restore model weights from previously saved model
    lhlB = lhl.eval(session=self.sess)
    print lhlA == lhlB
```

`lhlA` and `lhlB` are the last hidden layer weights before and after restoring and according to my code they match completely, namely the saved model is not loaded to the session. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround! Strangely the metagraph does not contain all the variables that I defined or assigns to them new names. For examples in the constructor I define the tensors that will carry the input feature vectors and the experimental values:

```
self.x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, feat_num], name='x')
self.y = tf.placeholder("float", [None], name='y')
```

However, when I do `tf.reset_default_graph()` and load the metagraph, I get the following list of variables:

```
[
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(300, 300) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(300,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(300, 1) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'Variable_3:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>
]
```

For the record, each input feature vector has 300 features. Anyway, when I later try to initiate training using:

```
_, c, p = self.sess.run([self.optimizer, self.cost, self.pred], 
feed_dict={self.x: batch_x, self.y: batch_y, self.isTrain: True})
```

I get an error like:

```
"TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor 'x' is not an element of this graph."
```

So, since every time I create an instance of `class TF_MLPRegressor()`, I define the network architecture within the constructor, I decided not to load the metagraph and it worked! I don't know why TF doesn't save all variables into the metagraph, maybe because I define explicitly the network architecture (I don't use wrappers or default layers) like in the example below:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/4_Utils/save_restore_model.py

To sum up, I save my models as described in my 1st message but to restore them I use this:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)
self.sess = tf.Session(config=self.config)  # create a new session to load saved variables
self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(self.checkpoint_dir)
saver.restore(sess=self.sess, save_path=ckpt)   # Restore model weights from previously saved model
```